# How to find out if a schedule triggered flow is running as a batch from the xml metadata?

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, schedulebatch, xml

This is the xml of schedule triggered flow. How to know if it is changing a batch of records?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionCalls>
        <name>Chatter_Post_to_Manager</name>
        <label>Chatter Post to Manager</label>
        <locationX>264</locationX>
        <locationY>516</locationY>
        <actionName>chatterPost</actionName>
        <actionType>chatterPost</actionType>
        <flowTransactionModel>CurrentTransaction</flowTransactionModel>
        <inputParameters>
            <name>text</name>
            <value>
                <elementReference>ChatterBody</elementReference>
            </value>
        </inputParameters>
        <inputParameters>
            <name>subjectNameOrId</name>
            <value>
                <elementReference>$Record.Id</elementReference>
            </value>
        </inputParameters>
        <storeOutputAutomatically>true</storeOutputAutomatically>
    </actionCalls>
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <decisions>
        <name>Contact_Found</name>
        <label>Contact Found?</label>
        <locationX>176</locationX>
        <locationY>396</locationY>
        <defaultConnector>
            <targetReference>Chatter_Post_to_Manager</targetReference>
        </defaultConnector>
        <defaultConnectorLabel>No</defaultConnectorLabel>
        <rules>
            <name>Yes</name>
            <conditionLogic>and</conditionLogic>
            <conditions>
                <leftValueReference>Find_Contacts</leftValueReference>
                <operator>IsNull</operator>
                <rightValue>
                    <booleanValue>false</booleanValue>
                </rightValue>
            </conditions>
            <label>Yes</label>
        </rules>
    </decisions>
    <environments>Default</environments>
    <interviewLabel>Weekly Check for Contacts {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <label>Weekly Check for Contacts</label>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>CanvasMode</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>AUTO_LAYOUT_CANVAS</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>AutoLaunchedFlow</processType>
    <recordLookups>
        <name>Find_Contacts</name>
        <label>Find Contacts</label>
        <locationX>176</locationX>
        <locationY>276</locationY>
        <assignNullValuesIfNoRecordsFound>false</assignNullValuesIfNoRecordsFound>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Contact_Found</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <filterLogic>and</filterLogic>
        <filters>
            <field>AccountId</field>
            <operator>EqualTo</operator>
            <value>
                <elementReference>$Record.Id</elementReference>
            </value>
        </filters>
        <getFirstRecordOnly>true</getFirstRecordOnly>
        <object>Contact</object>
        <storeOutputAutomatically>true</storeOutputAutomatically>
    </recordLookups>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>0</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Find_Contacts</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <object>Account</object>
        <schedule>
            <frequency>Weekly</frequency>
            <startDate>2023-05-25</startDate>
            <startTime>16:00:00.000Z</startTime>
        </schedule>
        <triggerType>Scheduled</triggerType>
    </start>
    <status>Draft</status>
    <textTemplates>
        <name>ChatterBody</name>
        <isViewedAsPlainText>false</isViewedAsPlainText>
        <text>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249); font-size: 12px; font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, &amp;quot;Courier New&amp;quot;, monospace; color: rgb(221, 17, 68);&quot;&gt;@[{!$Record.Owner.ManagerId}] This account has no contacts.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249); font-size: 12px; font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, &amp;quot;Courier New&amp;quot;, monospace; color: rgb(221, 17, 68);&quot;&gt;Owner: @[{!$Record.OwnerId}]&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</text>
    </textTemplates>
</Flow>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.